# Python ObjectListView -- how to split a list into two columns

Tags: python, listview, wxpython, objectlistview, objectlistview-python

I have an ObjectListView in wxPython that I would like to split into two identical lists that sit next to each other instead of one long list with a scrollbar.  So, instead of:

```
Column 1 -- Column 2 -- Column 3
data        data        data
data        data        data
```

I would like it to look like this:

```
Column 1 -- Column 2 -- Column 3     Column 1 -- Column 2 -- Column 3
data        data        data         data        data        data
```

Of course, with more data split evenly between them, if possible.  Is there a way to accomplish this without making two separate lists?  The reason I don't want to make two lists is that I have one large object list I'd like to pass it and with two lists I think I'd have to split the object in two and send a section to each list; if elegance is an option, I'd prefer it.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `list_B = list_A` you are not making "another" list, instead you are simply saying that there are 2 names for the same list, they both point to the same thing. You can use `id()` to check that this is true.

```
>>> list_A = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]
>>> id(list_A)
140229575676488
>>> list_B = list_A
>>> id(list_B)
140229575676488
>>> list_A
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list_B
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> list_A.append(9)
>>> list_A.append(10)
>>> list_A
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>> list_B
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Comment: I should have been more clear.  I'm not trying to split a list, I'm trying to split an objectlistview into two parts side by side instead of one part with a vertical scrollbar.  The two sections won't be copies, the second will be a continuation of the information from the first -- this is for spacing issues, I'd rather have two short lists side-by-side than one long list with a scrollbar.

Comment: Define a list with six columns and put the data accordingly.  To the user this will look like one list, there is no way, I know off, to put e.g. a separator between columns 3 and 4.

Comment: @linus72982 Ok, I see what you're driving at now. As Werner says, simply define the number of columns that you require assigning data as appropriate. You could of course define 7 columns with column 4 containing either a separation character or a colour to split your "2" data set parts. Be aware that you will have fill the last data set with nothing if the list has an odd number of data sets.